# How to get return value from shell script in expect script

Tags: shell, expect

In expect script im doing ssh and invoking a bash script which returns a value.How do I get the return value of shell script in expect script? Wait will return status of the Spawn but I want retrun value of the shell script.  Thanks in advance.

```
    #!/usr/bin/expect
    proc auto { } {
    global argv
    set timeout 120
    set ip XXXX.XXX.XX.XX
    set user name
    set password pass
    set ssh_opts {-o UserKnownHostsFile=/dev/null -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no}
    set script /path-to-script/test.sh
    spawn ssh {*}$ssh_opts $user@$ip sudo bash $script {*}$argv
    expect {
    "Password:" { send "$password\r"; exp_continue }
    timeout     { puts "Test failed." }
    eof
    }

    #  ssh command is now finished
    exp_close
    set info [wait]
    # [lindex $info 0] is the PID of the ssh process
    # [lindex $info 1] is the spawn id
    # [lindex $info 2] is the success/failure indicator
    if  {[lindex $info 2] == 0} {
       puts "exit status = [lindex $info 3]"
    }
   }
   auto {*}$argv
```